# Check the version of my app in the store

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to get the version of my app in the store and compare it with that I have installed on my device and if this is not the most recent block your app and make him get off the new version, is this possible?

Comment: This seems like a bad plan. If I downloaded an app that did this I would instantly delete it. Apple do a good enough job of telling users there is a newer version of the app available you should be forcing a user to update. Also I don't believe this is possible.

Comment: Write once web service that will return current version of the app that is on app store. When you open your application, consume that web service and compare with your current version.

Comment: @Popeye: Oracle does this every day ;)

Comment: @rokjarc seems like a good reason not to download it to me :-P I suppose my comment was just my opinion really but still I don't like being forced to update. I like to update when I feel I am ready.

Comment: @Popeye: of course, i agree :) one exception might be a business-type app with crucial update or bugfix but this kind of apps should use enterprise distribution anyway

Comment: @user2652032: though it is an interesting question and i hope you get an answer you should really reconsider your approach if you are thinking to use this in a public app. I would also - the same moment the app blocked me - delete the app and forget about it. Possibly i would write an angry review and request my money back.

Comment: @jcesar your comment is incorrect, there are several means to get the current version including the search API as mention below, web scrapping etc. but the search API is the best

Answer (score 2):

See this affiliate search API from Apple. It returns exactly what you want:

[Apple Search API](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html)